# Removing a specific recurring element in R

Tags: r

I have a data set that contains the wages for a census conducted in Italy. The number 9999999 states that the corresponding respondent's income is technically NULL (not available). I want to run a regression but I first need to get rid of all the elements with a 9999999 from the array.

When I run the following code:

```
data.frame(INCWAGE[1:10])
```

I get the output:

> 1        9999999
> 2        9999999
> 3           1180
> 4        9999999
> 5            500
> 6        9999999
> 7        9999999
> 8        9999999
> 9        9999999
> 10       9999999

P.S. I ran the the date set for elements 1 to 10 to simply the issue. The actual data contains around 100,000+ answers from the census.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your data into a data frame:

```
my_data= data.frame(my_data)
```

Then, run the following code (assuming your column is called "A")

```
new_data = subset(my_data, A!= 9999999)
```

Maybe this might work?